# What is a Poisson solid and what affect does it have on p and s waves?

Tags: geology, geophysics

What is a Poisson solid and what affect does it have on p and s waves?

Comment: Does this definition help. [An isotropic elastic material for which the Lamé elastic constants λ and μ are equal. A Poisson solid has Poisson’s ratio σ=1/4](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Dictionary:Poisson_solid)?